# ASDF throws system-out-of-date condition

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl, asdf

I'm using `ASDF` load `cl-ppcre` in a script file. The issue is `(progn (require :asdf) (require :cl-ppcre))` is perfectly fine in a top level, but if the same codes wrapped in a `handler-case`, a `system-out-of-date` condition will be caught by `handler-case` and the whole evaluation stops, and required packages won't be loaded. I just confirm the same issue also happens in a REPL. No matter what library I try to load, the same issue just happen in a `handler-case`. The following is a complete session:

```
; SLIME 2.27
CL-USER> (require :asdf)
NIL
CL-USER> (find-package :cl-ppcre)
NIL
CL-USER> (handler-case (require :cl-ppcre) (t (c) (format t "~a: ~a~%" (type-of c) c)))
SYSTEM-OUT-OF-DATE: system cl-ppcre is out of date
NIL
CL-USER> (find-package :cl-ppcre)
NIL
CL-USER> (require :cl-ppcre)
NIL
CL-USER> (find-package :cl-ppcre)
#<PACKAGE "CL-PPCRE">
CL-USER> (handler-case (require :cl-ppcre) (t (c) (format t "~a: ~a~%" (type-of c) c)))
NIL
CL-USER> (list (lisp-implementation-type) (lisp-implementation-version))
("SBCL" "2.2.4")
CL-USER> (asdf:asdf-version)
"3.3.1"
CL-USER> (directory "/home/pxie/common-lisp/*" :resolve-symlinks nil)
(#P"/home/pxie/common-lisp/alexandria/" #P"/home/pxie/common-lisp/cl-ppcre/")
```

According to ASDF manual, I put my libraries in `~/common-lisp directory`, and the libraries already compiled and saved in the `~/.cache/common-lisp directory`.

Any insight of what is going on in ASDF?

Comment: what does 'out of date' mean? Probably: there are "newer" source files than the compiled files? Maybe: there are newer source files than the ones the system was compiled from?

Comment: TLDR; instead of catching `t`, catch `error`: (handler-case … (error (c) … ))`.

Answer (score 5):

If you ask `handler-case` to catch *any* condition that is signalled, as you have done, it will do that, whether or not the condition is an error.  *You almost never want to do that.*

In particular if you look at `plan.lisp` in [the ASDF sources](https://gitlab.common-lisp.net/asdf/asdf) you will find

```
  ;; NB: This is not an error, not a warning, but a normal expected condition,
  ;; to be to signaled by FIND-SYSTEM when it detects an out-of-date system,
  ;; *before* it tries to replace it with a new definition.
  (define-condition system-out-of-date (condition)
    ...)
```

Comment: It is much more reasonable to handle only `error` conditions - and even then, it's better to be as specific as possible.

Comment: @Xach yes.  In fact I think that `(handler-case <code you did not write> (t ...))` is *never* safe because you just have no idea what is going on with conditions, and `handler-case` unwinds the stack.  `handler-bind` *could* be safe if your handlers decline the condition.